# Dart: Accessing a resource out side the project|web/ directory

Tags: file, directory, dart, dart-pub

I have a web-app(browser based) which needs to access a folder full of icons that resides outside the web folder.
This folder MUST be outside the web folder, and would ideally exist outside the project folder all together

however, when specifying the path to the folder neither "../" or making use of a symlink will work

when the page attempts to load the image I always get 
"[web] GET /Project|web/icons/img.png => Could not find asset Project|web/icons/img.png."

however I set the image source to "../icons/img.png"

how can i get dart to access this file properly

PS: I attempted a symlink to another part of the filesystem (where the images would be kept ideally) however this did not work either.

Comment: Why do the images have to be outside the web directory?

Comment: The images must be outside of the web directory because they need to be changed often and it is impracticable to have to change /web and then build again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server integrated into DartEditor or `pub serve` only serves directories that are added as folders to the files view. When you add the folder to DartEditor you should be able to access the files. This is just for development.

You have also to find a solution for when you deploy your server app. It would be a hazardous security issue when you could access files outside the project directory. Where should the server draw the line? If this would be possible your entire server would be accessible to the world.

Like @Robert asked, I also have a hard time imaging why the files must not be in the project folder.

If you want to reuse the icons/images between different projects you could create a resource package that contains only those images and add them as a dependency to your project.
If you want a better answer you need to provide more information about your requirements.

Comment: My the project is currently only meant for the local network.

Comment: And my web server is set up only to allow local computers. So security is not a huge issue. The files can be in the project folder, just not in web because if they are in web then I need to rebuild every time I change/add to the folder of images. Basically it is a point and click adventure game, and the mapping and image files need to be changed constantly. All I really need is a way to convince dart to look outside the /web or  /build/web directories

Comment: The servers are built to be safe anyway. I don't understand why you would need to build if images changes. You can also just copy them to the build output directory anytime later.

Comment: I don't know of a way to to this. I still can't understand your problem. Why do you think you have to recompile when you change images?

Comment: Coping and pasting is possible, however the point is not having to do anything. The images will be changing constantly by an automated process, and the dart code will not even necessarily know the names of the images. I need to have the images kept in one location, and this is not a problem except when testing the code with the dart editors development server. To be able to use the developement server for testing i have to change its base directory.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now but I have no solution. You can file a feature request at dartbug.com. Please crosslink between issue and this question when you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote your own server (by using the HttpServer class) it may be possible to use the VirtualDirectory to server your external files.

Looking at look the dartiverse_search example may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in the lib directory and refer to them via /packages/Project/...

Or in another package, in which case they would be in a different place in the file system. But as other people have said, your requirement seems odd.